# „Landsmann“ für Volkszugehörigkeit (ohne NS-Bezug)

Tags: single-word-request

Ich suche ein Wort für jemanden, der demselben Volk wie jemand anders angehört (z.B. Wort für zwei Juden, die aber nicht notwendigerweise in Israel leben).

Konkret habe ich in meiner Arbeit einen amerikanischen Juden bereits vorgestellt und wollte nun einen anderen etwa so einführen: „Sein Landsmann und <del>Volksgenosse</del> XYZ …“.

Gibt es so ein Wort ohne NS-Bezug?

Comment: Hier würde möglicherweise _Glaubensgenoose_ passen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Viele Wörter unterliegen der Ächtung nicht nur aufgrund des Mißbrauchs durch den Nationalsozialismus, sondern auch wegen ihrer rassistischen oder anderweitig diskriminierenden Bedeutung.

Die ist beim Adjektiv "ethnisch" zusammen mit einem näher spezifizierenden Substantiv  nicht der Fall. "Ethnisch" meint ganz ohne rassistische oder religiös diskriminierende Bedeutung die Zugehörigkeit zu einer kulturell oder sprachlich einheitlichen Volksgruppe.

Häufige Substantive, die mit ethnisch begleitet sind:

> ethnische Minderheit
>   ethnische Herkunft
>   ethnische Gruppe
>   ethnische Zugehörigkeit

Man wird aber bei Personen der selben ethnischen Herkunft diese gleich namentlich benennen, wie auch bereits in der Fragestellung geschehen (z.B. *zwei Juden*, *eine kurdische Familie*, *die Basken*,... etc.).

**Anmerkung:**

Man darf die ethnische Zugehörigkeit nicht herausstellen, wenn der übrige Kontext nichts mit der kulturellen oder religiösen Herkunft einer Person zu tun hat. Dies wäre eine Diskriminierung, wie wir sie hoffentlich nicht beabsichtigt hatten.

Comment: Wörter sind nicht von selbst diskriminierend oder nicht. Es muss immer eine diskriminierende Absicht und einen dementsprechenden Gebrauch geben, und wenn es diesen gibt sind auch keine Wörter immun gegen diskriminierenden Gebrauch.

Comment: @userunknown Deswegen sagte ich auch "Bedeutung", die kann sich nämlich über die Jahre und unter politischem Einfluss wandeln.

Answer (score 3):

"Landsmann" kann ohne weiteres für zwei Leute verwendet werden, die aus dem gleichen Land **stammen**, auch wenn sie im Augenblick nicht dort leben.

"Volk" ist ein vieldeutiger Begriff, gerade z.B. im Falle von Juden, die ihre Zusammengehörigkeit je nachdem geographisch, religiös, oder kulturell begründen könnten.

Für eine gemeinsame Religion gibt es z.B. "Glaubensgenosse". Mir fällt kein Wort ein, das eine gemeinsame Kultur ausdrücken würde.

Comment: Die Begriffe, die genau das ausdrücken, sind aufgrund von Mißbrauch durch die Nazis heute unbrauchbar geworden.